# How can I make Perl Dancer display my index page properly when the back button is used?

Tags: perl, dancer

When I fill out a form, press submit, and get the results page everything works perfectly. When I want to go back an fill out a new form the page is broken. It seems to be an amalgam of the index page and the results page. The only way I can get it to work is to re-start the Dancer web engine. Here is a copy of the pm that handles the routes:

```
package NNSP;
use Dancer2;
use Template;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
     template 'index';
};

post '/' => sub {
     set layout => 'result_format';
     template 'result';
};

true;
```

Comment: You should add `return` in front of your templates. It's not the issue here, but if you copy code later you might get in trouble.

Comment: @simbabque - I owe you a beer sometime for all the help!

Comment: I'd say come to this year's German Perl Workshop, but I think it is a little bit far away. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better do

`template 'result', $hashref, {layout => 'result_format'};`

instead of `set layout => 'result_format';`

or you should do

`set layout => 'default_layout';`
in `hook 'before'` or `'before_template'` as `set` sets global parameters.

Comment: and it's better to `return redirect` to "get" router (with setting some status parameter) to avoid double-post cases.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. However, to improve it, you should link to documentation that proves what you *think*.

Comment: `set layout` will modify layout "forever" (till the next set layout) for current process of the app. As it looks from your code you want to change layout for only one route, thats why

`template 'result', $hashref, {layout => 'result_format'};`